# load a 3D model with GLTFLoader (ThreeJS) in Reactjs without using React Fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gltf, threejs-editor

I want to load a 3D model with GLTFLoader but it gives me a syntax error

and I tried these ways

- const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
- const loader = new GLTFLoader(); after importing it

but all of the above didn't work with me

How can I solve this without using React Fiber?

[image]

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import Stats from "three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";

export default function Main() {
  useEffect(() => {
    /**
     * scene
     */
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    /**
     * textures
     */
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const matcapTexture = textureLoader.load("./static/textures/matcaps/1.png");

    /**
     * objects
     */

    // torus
    const torusGeometry = new THREE.TorusBufferGeometry(0.2, 0.1, 15, 45);
    // const torusMaterial = new THREE.MeshMatcapMaterial({ map: matcapTexture });
    const torusMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    const torus = new THREE.Mesh(torusGeometry, torusMaterial);
    torus.position.set(0, 0.3, 0);
    scene.add(torus);

    // 3D model
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    loader.load("./model_1/scene.gltf", (gltf) => {
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });

    /**
     * camera
     */
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.01,
      10000
    );
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 4);
    scene.add(camera);

 /**
 * renderer
 */
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvasElement");
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas,
  antialias: true,
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, 400);
renderer.setClearColor("white");
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing it in public folder is not a solution. What if you are getting 3D model from server?
The issue is that your react component rendered before getting gltf load. So you need to load it before render. So the easy and Quick solution is to use useGLTF hook. https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#usegltf

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I should have put the model's files in the public folder